# In the Jurassic park novel what's the deal with the second blackout?

Tags: jurassic-park

In the Jurassic Park novels the raptors first appear as enemies for the protagonists when the auxiliary generator runs out of fuel. But Arnold claims that the fences were not active since they restarted the system some time before, since the auxiliary generator does not have enough power for it.

And unlike in the movie, Nedry did switch off all fences and other security measurements including the raptors' fence the evening before.

And in fact they were out all along anyways.

So, why are the raptors only appearing once the auxiliary generator is out of fuel?

Comment: Probably it takes a little while for the raptors to realise that the fences are out.

Comment: Maybe they associated the sound of the generator with the zappy zappy.